# Error when I call https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/upgradableApp

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

When I call the API to upgrade domains from OAuth1.0 to OAuth2.0 I've got following message:

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"backendError","message":"Backend Error"}],"code":500,"message":"Backend Error"}}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Hi Tangyy, did you get solution for this? We too facing the same issue while using https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/upgradableApp

Comment: Hi,Yes when the app have been validated, it has solved the problem ;)

Comment: Hi Tangyy,we have same kind of issue reported here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099541/how-to-authenticate-upgradeableapp-api-for-migrating-google-apps-marketplace-app
can you please check and help?