# How to authenticate UpgradeableApp API for migrating Google Apps Marketplace Apps from v1 to v2?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

we are using https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/upgradableApp to migrate the oauth1.0 app to oauth2.0 app.

We are referring to https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v1migratev2

while making the call we are getting "Invalid OAuth Header" error (401)

We are using consumer key and consumer secret alone. we are not using any token.

I am sure that we are missing something here. But not sure what it is. Any pointers to this issue will help us.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the sample code

    `HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    PutMethod method = new PutMethod("https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/upgradableApp///");
    method.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "oAuth");
    method.addRequestHeader("Consumer Key","");
    method.addRequestHeader("Consumer Key Secret","");
    try {
        int status = client.executeMethod(method);
        System.out.println("status:" + status);
        System.out.println("response:" + method.getResponseBodyAsString());
    }
    catch (HttpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`

### Result :

> status:::401
>   response::{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"authError","message":"Invalid OAuth > header","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"In
>   valid OAuth header"}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We tried with the following code using OAuth 1.0 API for Google and it worked fine.

```
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.PUT, api.getUpdateDomainEndpoint(listingId, chromeWSId, domain));
request.addOAuthParameter(OAuthConstants.TIMESTAMP, api.getTimestampService().getTimestampInSeconds());
request.addOAuthParameter(OAuthConstants.NONCE, api.getTimestampService().getNonce());
request.addOAuthParameter(OAuthConstants.CONSUMER_KEY, config.getApiKey());
request.addOAuthParameter(OAuthConstants.SIGN_METHOD, api.getSignatureService().getSignatureMethod());
request.addOAuthParameter(OAuthConstants.VERSION, getVersion());
request.addOAuthParameter(OAuthConstants.SIGNATURE, getSignature(request, token));
String oauthHeader = api.getHeaderExtractor().extract(request);
request.addHeader(OAuthConstants.HEADER, oauthHeader);
```

Comment: What library are you using here, and do you know of a PHP equivalent?